# Can the word 'celibate' be used for women too?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

Can the word 'celibate' be used for women too? Is there any 'ing' form of 'celibate'? 
Can we also say,"She has become/turned celibate"?

Comment: OED do actually have an entry for ***celibate*** as a *verb* usage *(to restrain from marriage, compel to celibacy)*. But the only citation is from 1659, and they say it's a "nonce-word" anyway. Most instances of ***celibating*** today are likely to either be mispronunciations of ***celebrating***, or (either ignorant or facetious) alternatives to ***celibacy***.

Answer (score 2):

The word *celibate* can be used for a woman too.

The [Huff Post Entertainment](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2010/04/11/lady-gaga-explains-why-sh_n_533187.html) has the headline

> **Lady Gaga Explains Why She's Celibate**

I could not find *celibating* from any authentic source including COCAE.